# Custom Columns WordPress Admin

Tags: customization, wp-admin, columns

I am just about finished creating custom columns through the WordPress admin panel.

The custom post type I am using is called "slides". I figured out how to add the column titles and all of the column content (because they're WordPress defaults)...what I am missing is how do I add content to the "thumbnail" column? Some kind of if statement like: if admin-thumbnail exists display the admin-thumbnail image...which sounds simple enough, I just don't know how to add it to that specific column.

The code I have so far is: http://pastebin.com/YfuYUW5c.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris,

I modified the following (and the code is working!): http://pastebin.com/HZWgHrZf.

I got it here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types

For every column you simply add another case :)

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

first create the new column:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'c3m_new_column');
function c3m_new_column( $defaults ) {
    $dfaults['post_thumbnail'] = 'Post Thumbnail';
    return $defaults;
}
```

Now the function to output the thumbnails in the column:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'c3m_custom_column', 10, 2);
function c3m_custom_column( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ($column_name == 'post_thumbnail') {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $img_url[0] ).'" />';
        } else { echo 'No Post Thumbnail Set'; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the global $post; in c3m_custom_column?

Comment: no, you do not need , also, you can simply use `the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) )` //or other size .. instead of `$img_URL array` ..